# Asm equivalent to a delphi procedure

Tags: delphi, assembly, x86-64

I have a simple delphi function called SetCompare that compares two singles and if they are not equal then one value is set to the other.

```
procedure SetCompare( A : single; B : single );
  begin
    if( A <> B ) then
      A := B;
  end;
```

I am trying  to convert this into asm as such:

```
procedure SetCompare( A : Single; B : Single ); register;
  begin
    asm
      mov EAX,A
      mov ECX,B
      cmp EAX,ECX
      jne SetValue

      @SetValue:
      mov EAX,ECX
    end;
  end;
```

Will this work?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Have you tested your code? It works?

Comment: No. Singles are 32 bit floating point types, but in your assembler, you are comparing integer registers. I do wonder, however, why you call this function SetCompare. It does not compare sets.

Comment: And, as RBA said, instead of asking "will this work?", you can easily test this yourself. Just compile it and see if it properly compares two Singles.

Comment: And `jne SetValue` when Setvalue is the next line is nonsense too.

Comment: procedure != function. None of your code makes any sense. Also note that parameters are passed by value here (i.e. a copy is passed). Any alteration you make to the parameters does not leave the procedure. If you wanted that to happen you'd need to have `var` parameters. Please get a copy of http://www.marcocantu.com/objectpascalhandbook/ or simular.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to asm? It's bad Delphi code (even if you fix the mistakes), and would be worse in asm! Step back and think about what you're doing: 1) if A and B are different: you do a comparison and an assignment. 2) if A and B are the same: you do a comparison and a jump. ***I.e. 2 operations in both cases*** But if you want A to be the same as B, simply assigning `A := B;` is a ***single operation***. So there are no performance benefits to be gained with your approach - you only create potential for unexpected behaviour due to floating point subtleties you haven't considered.

Comment: If you're trying to expand your horizons and learn assembler, then great! But might I suggest you learn to write good Delphi code first.

Comment: Honestly, if you're setting one to be equal to the other if they are not the same, wouldn't it be easier to just always set A to B?

Comment: It's bad idea to use asm in cross-platform language. Because this asm part will work only in x86, and will not work in x64, Android (ARM), MacOS (x64) and iOS (ARM).

Answer (score 8):

> Will this work?

No this will not work, because floating point comparison is not the same as binary comparison. For instance `0` and `-0` have different bit patterns, but compare as equal. Similarly, `NaN` compares unequal to all values, including a `NaN` with the same bit pattern.

The simplest way to work out how to write your code is to get the compiler to compile the Pascal code, and inspect the generated assembly code.

Some asides:

- Your function is pointless anyway, because it returns no value and has no side effects.
- If performance matters enough to write assembler, then you should write pure assembler functions, rather than inline `asm` blocks in a Pascal function. Which in any case is not supported by the x64 compiler.
- Your arguments are already in registers, so it makes little sense to copy them around to other registers. For x86 code, `A` arrives in `EAX`, and `B` arrives in `EDX`. Given that `EAX` already contains `A`, why would you copy it into `EAX`? It is already there. And `B` is already in `EDX`, why copy it to `ECX`? For x64 code, the two arguments are passed in floating point registers, and can be compared there directly. As soon as your start writing assembler you need to understand the register use of the calling convention.
- Your `jne` is pointless. If execution does not take the jump, then it moves to the next line of code. Which is where you jumped to.

Comment: all fine and well, but disassembly is often full of code like `MOV EAX,[EBP-$08]` which is not easily readable at all. It takes some time to actually get used to this and being able to read such code.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Like many things in life, knowledge and expertise are required.

Comment: indeed. But I don't think that looking at the generated assembly code is a help to beginners. It is probably even confusing.

Comment: Everything is going to be confusing for a beginner. But not everybody reading this will be a beginner. I know that I would study the code emitted by one or more compilers, and then do further research guided by that. It's also not really our job to teach a complete beginner without the knowledge or experience to write asm, how to do that. That's just too much.